# Hide elements in HTML-mails on Apple Mail

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-client

Is there a way to hide elements (e.g. s or s) in HTML-mails when they are viewed by Apple mail-clients (Apple Mail on Desktop OS and iOS)?

Maybe there is an easy way via CSS's -webkit properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use media query to do so, here is some extra code. And then by usin displaying none or block you can hide elements.
I hope you are aware of media queries.

```
 <!-- iPhone standard resolution 320x460  (landscape not needed because all web apps start portrait on iPhone) -->
<link  rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-320x460.jpg" media="(device-width: 320px)" />
<!-- iPhone high resolution (retina) 640x920 pixels (landscape not needed because all web apps start portrait on iPhone) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-640x920.jpg" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
<!-- iPad Portrait 768x1004 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-768x1004.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" />
<!-- iPad Landscape 748x1024 (yes, a portrait image but with content rotated 90 degrees - allows 20px for status bar) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-748x1024.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" />
<!-- iPad retina Portrait 1536x2008 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-1536x2008.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
<!-- iPad retina Landscape 1496x2048 (yes, a portrait image but with content rotated 90 degrees - allows 40px for status bar) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-1496x2048.jpg" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

Comment: thanks, looks like an option. is it also possible with non-mobile devices like iMac?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For details please refer to this link.
Here you can find different devices configuration for iMac as well.

http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/media-width-for-responsive-design

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only for iOS devices. [Here's a full list.](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

However it's really almost impossible to try and detect a desktop Mac through a media query. Most iMacs have a display of 1920x1080, the same as all 1080p monitors. You'll have the same problem with their laptops. And you can't use javascript in emails so there's no way to browser-sniff that way.

Most importantly, Apple Mail is not nearly as popular as webmail services like GMail and Yahoo, which strip any media queries.